# No optimization model was found Excel solver

Tags: solver

I am trying to use the solver add-in in google sheet. But when I am setting up the optimization problem, without any constraints on variables, I am seeing following message;

**No optimization model was found Excel solver**
I am trying to find the details about this error, but not finding much about it. Can I please get some help here?